# Retrieving test duration from NUnit TestContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I would like to be able to access the duration of a test in my test code. I have been looking at the `TestContext` class in NUnit, but while I find information abut "FullName", I cannot figure out where to access the duration of a test.

```
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName); 
}
```

Apart from the full name of the test, I can access a `Properties` dictionary, but in all cases, only value is a "_CATEGORIES" entry.

How do I accomplish what I want to do?

Thanks :-)

Comment: The `Properties` dictionary contains other information about tests, probably, description or metadata, but not the information you are looking for. Check the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible to get this information from NUnit `TestContext` because NUnit  doesn't provide such information there. Basically, unit tests should be fast and tell you if some parts are broken, but don't use them as a time registration system.

My question is **Why do you need this information in unit tests?**

**NUnit provides attributes to define time limits** for tests: [`Timeout`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.6)  and [`MaxTime`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=maxtime&r=2.6). If the test case runs longer than the time specified, both attributes will be used to tell about this failure. If the `Timeout` attribute is defined, the test will be interrupted as soon as possible. If the `MaxTime` attribute is defined the test case will not be interrupted.

You could also **check a file with test results** `TestResult.xml` and find an attribute which represents execution time (it's called `time`). If your boss wants something good-looking, HTML report can be generated using a special tool [nunit-results](https://github.com/CharliePoole/nunit-results).

Do you still want to know **execution time in the code**? Inherit your test from this class:

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class BaseTestClass
{
    private Stopwatch _stopWatch;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();   
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        _stopWatch.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Excution time for {0} - {1} ms",
            TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name,
            _stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        // ... add your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sergii, sorry that I did not reply earlier. I needed the execution times to be able to track performance over time as improvements were made on the code. I ended up using the Xml-test-result and with at bit of XPath magic extract the execution times for the different tests. It sort of worked fine :-)

Comment: Oh, the XPath I used was this: //node[@status='Success' and @kind='NUnit Test' and contains(@name, '<name of my test>')]/@duration